# Pybind11 - class without copy constructor/operator

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, pybind11

I have a library that I am trying to interface from C++ to python using pybind11.

I am finding myself in the following configuration. I have a C++ class that doesn't allow the copy (copy constructor and operator= are deleted). But this class is an output of another method. How do I allow interfacing this class in pybind11?

As an example, I want to do the interface of the class `A`, that I get from pybind having a pybind11/python interface:

```
A& foo() { ... };
```

With a class declaration of A that looks like that:

```
class A {
  A (B&);
  A (const A&) = delete;
  A& operator= (const A&) = delete;
};
```

How do I manage to have a pybind11 interface of `A`?

Comment: Is your B interface is visible to Python?

Comment: Excellent question. In my use case, no. So I don't want to define a constructor for it. But if it is another problem to handle, I may need to create another question for it. So far, what I do is I create an empty constructor that throws when called. It is the lesser of two evils (one problem at a time ;) ).

Comment: Or another way: You really add default constructor to A, but instead of throwing, the created instance holds internal state as "invalid" or "empty".  And then, if you call some method of such instance, the method throws some kind of "Invalid State" exception.

This technique used by C++, for example, to create "non-valid" future<T> which not accepted from corresponded promise<T>. The same are "empty" smart pointers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `return_value_policy` to `reference`?

```
class A {
public:
    A() = default;
    A (const A&) = delete;
    A& operator= (const A&) = delete;
};

A& foo()
{
    static A a;
    return a;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m)
{
    py::class_<A>(m, "A");
    m.def("foo", &foo, py::return_value_policy::reference);
}
```